# Visual Studio - Open program in current users files

Tags: c#

So basically I'm using Visual Studio and I'm trying to get it so when the user clicks on a button, it opens a directory or program although I need it to detect the current user, so that it doesn't open my users files.

Comment: when they open a directory, they can still navigate through your files right?

Comment: Very unclear what you are looking for... How "current user" is different from "my user", do you need help with adding button to VS or you are building some console/WinForm/WebForm/WPF project,...

Comment: Are you talking about when you open an app and you set the "Start in" folder available in the File Properties? Please see [ask] and try to be clearer next time.

Answer (score -1):

There are so many ways in .Net to get the current user. The most common answer you will find is `String UserName = Environment.UserName;`